# Java Client Server Model

Tags: java

is it possible to send a stream of UDP packets let say 15 packets of size 1500 with each packet time separation  is 5 seconds or it can me some milli second value,  using java client server model ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just call [`Thread.sleep()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) between each datagram.

Comment: @ Inerdia .. so i should create a loop of UDP packets and i can set the inter packet time separation using the command thread.sleep() in between each datagram. can u send me an example how i can do that . actually i am new in java and need a small guide line if u can help ..

Comment: @ Inerdia .. can u send me some example or a good link which can help me in implementing this java code ===???

Answer (score 1):

No because in general it is not even possible to send UDP DatagramSocket larger than 534 bytes unless you are in complete control of the entire network topology, and once you get above the path MTU you are introducing IP fragmentation which heightens the already high risk of packet loss.

Comment: @ EJP so it means i cant send a packet having size 1500 bytes using java UDP datagram client server model ???

Comment: @jad Essentially. Even an Ethernet will impose a smaller packet size than that. The datagram will be sent, but fragmented at the IP level, increasing the chance of it being lost, as there is no UDP process for requesting missing fragments to be retransmitted.